# How to convert a string to an enum?

Tags: enums, casting, rust

My [original approach](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=08f08974535dcbbab05a870695c0dcc8&version=stable&backtrace=0) was to create method called `to_str()` which will return a slice, but I am not sure that it is correct approach because this code doesn't compile.

```
enum WSType {
    ACK,
    REQUEST,
    RESPONSE,
}

impl WSType {
    fn to_str(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            ACK => "ACK",
            REQUEST => "REQUEST",
            RESPONSE => "RESPONSE",            
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = "ACK";
    // test
    match val {
        ACK.to_str() => println!("ack"),
        REQUEST.to_str() => println!("ack"),
        RESPONSE.to_str() => println!("ack"),
        _ => println!("unexpected"),
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, you are right it doesn't compile. I think I should mention it in original post. I was trying to match random string slice to specific enum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct thing is to implement [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). Here, I'm matching against the string literals that represent each enum variant:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum WSType {
    Ack,
    Request,
    Response,
}

impl std::str::FromStr for WSType {
    type Err = String;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s {
            "ACK" => Ok(WSType::Ack),
            "REQUEST" => Ok(WSType::Request),
            "RESPONSE" => Ok(WSType::Response),
            _ => Err(format!("'{}' is not a valid value for WSType", s)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let as_enum: WSType = "ACK".parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", as_enum);

    let as_enum: WSType = "UNKNOWN".parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", as_enum);
}
```

To print a value, implement [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) or [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) (I've derived `Debug` here). Implementing `Display` also gives you `.to_string()`.

---

In certain cases, there are crates that can reduce some of the tedium of this type of conversion. [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum) is one such crate:

```
use strum_macros::EnumString;

#[derive(Debug, EnumString)]
#[strum(serialize_all = "shouty_snake_case")]
enum WSType {
    Ack,
    Request,
    Response,
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, it looks perfect.